Asymptotic Freedom QCD
I'm trying to understand the derivation of asymptotic freedom with the renormalisation group equations. I'm reading Taizo Muta's book on QCD. What I don't understand is how he obtains the last expression for $Z_g$. Im thinking since $Z_3$ is the only parameter with $T_R$ and it is in the denominator how does it switch to the numerator. I also do not understand why $\alpha$ cancels out at the end, because the denominator should have a higher power in $\alpha$, since there is a product between two $Z_i$.


The author performs Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}\approx 1+x$ up to $O\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)$.
This is justified by the fact that terms of order $O\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\right)$ or higher would also have contributions from 2-loop diagrams, which are not done by the author.

You might complain about the fact that the terms of $O(1/\epsilon^22)$
are actually ENORMOUS as we take $\epsilon→0$. I am actually unsure about how to justify this, but maybe you have to use the fact that at some point you multiply by $\epsilon$ to make this finite.

Thanks a lot Gabriel! Now it makes sense :).

The point is that the 1/epsilon^2 contributions come with powers of g_R^4 (and as you mention, the full 1/epsilon^2 term will contain two-loop diagram contributions). Dimensionally regulated perturbation theory is consistent if you work order by order in g_R (the expression in eq. 3.4.5 is the full result at O(g_R^2))
